# R - construct sparse matrix from list of lists

Tags: python, r, pandas

Using python and pandas I can easily construct a sparse DataFrame from a list of dictionary objects. The following code snippet shows how this can be done in pandas:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd; (pd.DataFrame([{'a':1, 'b':10}, 
                                            {'d':99, 'c':1},
                                            {'b':1, 'd': 4}])
                                .fillna(0))
Out[1]: 
     a     b    c     d
0  1.0  10.0  0.0   0.0
1  0.0   0.0  1.0  99.0
2  0.0   1.0  0.0   4.0
```

What if I want to easily reproduce this behavior in R? Let's suppose that I have the following variable:

```
values <- list(list(a = 1, b = 10),
               list(d = 99, c = 1),
               list(b = 1, d = 4))
```

Then, how the same result achieved in python can be obtained using R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `dplyr` you could do it like this:

```
library(dplyr)
values %>% bind_rows() %>% mutate_all(function(x) coalesce(x, 0))

# A tibble: 3 × 4
      a     b     d     c
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1    10     0     0
2     0     0    99     1
3     0     1     4     0
```

Comment: Nice to know about `bind_rows`! Pretty elegant solution, indeed.

Answer (score 5):

We can use `melt` with `xtabs` in `R`

```
library(reshape2)
xtabs(value~L1 + L2, melt(values))
#     L2
#L1   a  b  c  d
#  1  1 10  0  0
#  2  0  0  1 99
#  3  0  1  0  4
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution with `plyr` package:

```
ldply(values, data.frame)

   a  b  d  c
1  1 10 NA NA
2 NA NA 99  1
3 NA  1  4 NA


# mutate each to replace NA with 0
ldply(values, data.frame) %>% 
     mutate_each(funs(replace(., is.na(.), 0)))

  a  b  d c
1 1 10  0 0
2 0  0 99 1
3 0  1  4 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Using base R to construct a matrix, you could do the following.

first, the set up

```
# flatten list to pull out info for matrix construction
flat <- unlist(values)
# build a 0 matrix with correct dimensions and column names
myMat <- matrix(0, nrow=length(values), ncol=length(unique(names(flat))),
                dimnames=list(NULL, sort(unique(names(flat)))))
```

Now, fill in the matrix

```
for(i in seq_along(values)) myMat[i, names(values[[i]])] <- unlist(values[[i]])
```

This results in

```
myMat
     a  b c  d
[1,] 1 10 0  0
[2,] 0  0 1 99
[3,] 0  1 0  4
```

If you actually wanted a data.frame, you can convert the matrix with the `as.data.frame` or `data.frame` functions.